# Как создать миллиард записей в бд?

Tags: django, django-orm

Если создаю обычным образом:

```
Model.objects.create()
```

То на моём компьютере получается миллион-полтора записей за час, и естественно создавать миллиард очень не оправданно по времени. Но я слышал, что люди создавали миллиард за пару часов. Может есть нормальные способы сделать это быстро с помощью **django-orm**?

Comment: а какая ваша основная задача? На скорость работы будут огромную роль иметь скорость и размер оперативной памяти и тип жёсткого диска (SSD).  Но миллиард записей - это гигабайт 100 (100 байт на запись - совсем не много), а скорее счёт идёт на терабайты. Поэтому вопрос - зачем вам это?

Comment: Не знал, что так много места займёт, не подумал. На самом деле просто любопытство. Для тестов то всё равно нужно как-то базу заполнять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Вижу что просмотров больше чем на другие вопросы, а значит темой люди интересуются. И так как ответа на задачу всё-таки не поступило, то решил опубликовать своё решение, в надежде, что это поможет кому-то ещё.*

**Создавать много записей нужно с помощью метода `QuerySet.bulk_create` метод позволяет одним запросом создавать множество объектов.**

Вот примерно такой сценарий я написал для заполнения своей бд:

```
def создать_записи():
    счётчик = 0
    КОЛ_ОБЪЕКТОВ_В_ЗАПРОСЕ = 10000

    def сгенерировать_10000_моделей():
        for _ in range(КОЛ_ОБЪЕКТОВ_В_ЗАПРОСЕ):
            nonlocal счётчик
            счётчик += 1
            if not счётчик % 100000:
                print("создано объектов: ", счётчик)
            yield МояМодель(поле_модели=счётчик)

    for х in range(10):
        for у in range(0, 1000000, КОЛ_ОБЪЕКТОВ_В_ЗАПРОСЕ):
            МояМодель.objects.bulk_create(
                сгенерировать_10000_моделей()
            )
```

В итоге такого подхода экономится 9999 запросов можно делать и по 100 000, если позволяют мощности железа. **Миллион записей, таким способом, создаются уже не за час, а за пять минут.**

Если есть замечания - высказывайте. Если решение оказалось вам полезным - оцените это. Хотя бы буду знать, что не зря старался, и помог кому-то.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь помимо аппаратных возможностей немаловажную роль играет и программное обеспечение используемой БД(СУБД). Например, если вы пытаетесь заполнить таблицу, у которой проиндексировано хотя бы 1 поле, а фреймворк django, насколько помню, в автоматическом режиме индексирует уникальные поля(unique index), первичные ключи(primary key) и внешние(foreign key), то каждая атомарная вставка будет провоцировать перестроение индексной таблицы, что при вставке массива из 10^9 записей, конечно же, скажется на времени.

Кроме того, как уже было неоднократно сказано, возьмите листок бумаги и прикиньте приблизительный суммарный размер данных, который будет храниться не где-то в воздухе, а на вашем HDD.

И даже если вам удастся аллоцировать такой размер данных где-то у себя, то при попытке "игр" с этими данными вы едва ли будете в большом восторге - так, например, привычный безобидный с первого взгляда селект может выполняться порядка 10 минут, а если на уровне БД не предусмотрен контроль по количеству выгружаемых данных, то вы рискуете переполнить свою ОЗУ, что приведет к эмуляции ОЗУ через HDD => еще больших потерях производительности.

Answer (score 0):

Для ускорения операции лучше пользоваться встроенными средствами бд. Например в постгресе есть функция generate_series